# How to write realy good animation for changing screens

Tags: android, animation

So I wrote an app for android, and now i'm trying to add some animations to it. All animation I want is when i change screen. So I tried that animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="200" />
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="50%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="180"/>
</set>
```

It looks quite ok, but not realy perfect. I was wondering if there are any animation's online, but i found none. Also the default animations, don't do the trick for me. Any ideas or samples for good animation? I'm looking for something realy simple like screnn rotate in or something.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) android card flip animation from the developer site. You can also download the sample code.

Comment: For some reason using that it couses my app to crash :S